# How do I allow java to have permission to read and write to files on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, csv

I'm testing some new code with java and I'm trying to create a new text file. But, when I run it I get a "Permission Denied" error.

All my users are set to read and write permissions and I went through all my folders and set them to read and write using "chmod 777 /path_name"

```
public class xplrCSV {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(File.separator + "MOCK_DATA1.txt");
        f.createNewFile();//Line 19  
    }  
}
```

I would expect this code to create a new file however the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at xplrCSV.main(xplrCSV.java:19)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write into the root folder anyway?

Comment: I'm assuming you did not literally set ALL of your folders to this permission.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the java application with a user that has permission to write/read files in the requested directory.

You can't change permits to read/write files of the current user used to run JVM for security reasons.

Check if you have the rights to access the file. If yes it is possible that the file already exists and is already opened by another process or application that lock it.

Comment: If it's 777 permissions, why does the user still matter? I think the problem is that the path in the code is wrong

Comment: Where in the code would I change the file path and where should I set the path to be able to access it?